# Error que termina la simulación de mi app

Tags: ios, xcode

Esta aplicación funcionaba correctamente, pero al hacer modificaciones manda este error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7fd1e3701460> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
        *** First throw call stack:
        (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f371f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010edebdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
            2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f371ba9 -[NSException raise] + 9
            3   Foundation                          0x000000010e794f5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
            4   UIKit                               0x000000010d681923 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
            5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2b2b10 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
            6   UIKit                               0x000000010d680306 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
            7   UIKit                               0x000000010d68253d -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 223
            8   UIKit                               0x000000010d2e0f5e -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 57
            9   UIKit                               0x000000010d2e133c -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
            10  UIKit                               0x000000010d2dfca1 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1383
            11  UIKit                               0x000000010d2dcff0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
            12  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f8947ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
            13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f894b1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
            14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f29e0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
            15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f293fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
            16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f293483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
            17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f292e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
            18  UIKit                               0x000000010d2dc98d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
            19  UIKit                               0x000000010d2e1676 UIApplicationMain + 171
            20  empresas                            0x000000010d2132bf main + 111
            21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001138f292d start + 1
```

El .h:

```
//  SwitchClass.h clase para traer las otras ventanas, tiene como inicio el SwitchClass.xib 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class primero;
@class segundo;
@class tercero;
@class cuarto;
@class quinto;
@class sexto;
@class septimo;
@class octavo;
@class noveno;
@class decimo;
@class enviar;
@class cero;

@interface SwitchClass : UIViewController{

    primero *primerot;
    segundo *segundot;
    tercero *tercerot;
    cuarto *cuartot;
    quinto *quintot;
    sexto *sextot;
    septimo *septimot;
    octavo *octavot;
    noveno *novenot;
    decimo *decimot;
    enviar *enviart;
    cero *cerot;

    NSString *dataFilePath;
    NSString *choice;
    NSString *choice2;
    NSString *choice3;
    NSString *choice4;
    NSString *choice5;
    NSString *choice6;
    NSString *choice7;
    NSString *choice8;
    NSString *choice9;
    NSString *choice10;
    NSString *choice11;
    NSString *choice12;
    NSString *choice13;
    NSString *choice14;
    NSString *choice15;
    NSString *choice16;
    NSString *choice17;
    NSString *choice18;
    NSString *choice19;
    NSString *choice20;
    NSString *choice21;    

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) primero *primerot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) segundo *segundot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) tercero *tercerot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) cuarto  *cuartot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) quinto *quintot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) sexto *sextot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) septimo *septimot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) octavo *octavot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) noveno *novenot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) decimo *decimot;
@property (nonatomic, retain) enviar *enviart;
@property (nonatomic, retain) cero *cerot;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *dataFilePath;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice3;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice4;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice5;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice6;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice7;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice8;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice9;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice10;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice11;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice12;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice13;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice14;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice15;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice16;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice17;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice18;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice19;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice20;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *choice21;

- (IBAction) swichviews: (id)sender;
- (IBAction) anterior: (id)sender;
- (IBAction) enviar: (id)sender;
@end
```

El .m:

```
//  SwitchClass.m
#import "SwitchClass.h"
#import "primero.h"
#import "segundo.h"
#import "tercero.h"
#import "cuarto.h"
#import "quinto.h"
#import "sexto.h"
#import "septimo.h"
#import "octavo.h"
#import "noveno.h"
#import "decimo.h"
#import "enviar.h"
#import "cero.h"

@interface SwitchClass ()
@end

@implementation SwitchClass
@synthesize primerot;
@synthesize segundot;
@synthesize tercerot;
@synthesize cuartot;
@synthesize quintot;
@synthesize sextot;
@synthesize septimot;
@synthesize octavot;
@synthesize novenot;
@synthesize decimot;
@synthesize enviart;
@synthesize cerot;
@synthesize dataFilePath;
@synthesize choice;
@synthesize choice2;
@synthesize choice3;
@synthesize choice4;
@synthesize choice5;
@synthesize choice6;
@synthesize choice7;
@synthesize choice8;
@synthesize choice9;
@synthesize choice10;
@synthesize choice11;

@synthesize choice12;
@synthesize choice13;
@synthesize choice14;
@synthesize choice15;
@synthesize choice16;
@synthesize choice17;
@synthesize choice18;
@synthesize choice19;
@synthesize choice20;
@synthesize choice21;

- (IBAction)enviar: (id)sender{

    int i;
    if(self.cerot !=nil){  i = 1;}
    if(self.primerot !=nil){  i = 2;}
    if(self.segundot !=nil){  i = 3;}
    if(self.tercerot !=nil){  i = 4;}
    if(self.cuartot !=nil){  i = 5;}
    if(self.quintot !=nil){  i = 6;}
    if(self.sextot !=nil){ i =7;}
    if(self.septimot !=nil){ i =8;}
    if(self.octavot !=nil){ i =10;}
    if(self.decimot !=nil){ i =11;}
    if(self.enviart !=nil){ i =12;}

    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
        [cerot.view removeFromSuperview];
        cerot = nil;
        break;
    case 2:
        [primerot.view removeFromSuperview];
        primerot = nil;
        break;
    case 3:
        [segundot.view removeFromSuperview];
        segundot = nil;
        break;
    case 4:
        [tercerot.view removeFromSuperview];
        tercerot = nil;
        break;
    case 5:
        [cuartot.view removeFromSuperview];
        cuartot = nil;
        break;
    case 6:
        [quintot.view removeFromSuperview];
        quintot = nil;
        break;
    case 7: 
        [sextot.view removeFromSuperview];
        sextot = nil;      
        break;
    case 8:
        [septimot.view removeFromSuperview];
        septimot = nil;
        break;
    case 10:
        [octavot.view removeFromSuperview];
        octavot = nil;
        break;
    case 9:
        [novenot.view removeFromSuperview];
        //[quintot release];
        novenot = nil;
        break;
    case 11:
        [decimot.view removeFromSuperview];
        decimot = nil;
        break;
    case 12:
        {
        UIAlertView *alert4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Coloque Password y envie Encuestas" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert4 show];
        enviart = nil;
        }
        break;
    }
    enviar *sende = [[enviar alloc]initWithNibName:@"enviar" bundle:nil];
    self.enviart =sende;

    [self.view insertSubview:sende.view atIndex:0];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (IBAction) swichviews: (id)sender{

    int i;
    if(self.cerot !=nil){  i = 1;}
    if (self.cuartot!=nil){ i=2;}
    if (self.quintot!= nil){ i=3;}
    if(self.primerot !=nil){ i = 4;}
    if (self.septimot!=nil){ i=5;}
    if (self.segundot!=nil){ i=8;}
    if (self.decimot!=nil){ i=10;}
    if (self.octavot!=nil){ i=11;}

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            if ([cerot.mesero.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                UIAlertView *alert4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Fallo corrobore su password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert4 show];

                 }
            else {

           cuarto *quin = [[cuarto alloc]initWithNibName:@"cuarto" bundle:nil];
            self.cuartot = quin;
            choice= cerot.mesero.text;
            [cerot.view removeFromSuperview];
            cerot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:cuartot.view atIndex:0];
                 }
        }
            break;

     case 2:
        {
              choice2= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho11.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice2 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho11.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice2 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho11.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice2 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho11.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice2 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }
            choice3= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho12.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice3 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho12.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice3 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho12.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice3 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho12.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice3 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }
            choice4= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho13.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice4 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho13.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice4 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho13.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice4 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho13.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice4= @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }
            choice5= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho14.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice5 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho14.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice5 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho14.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice5 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho14.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice5 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }

            choice6= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho15.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice6 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho15.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice6 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho15.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice6 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho15.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice6 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }

            choice7= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho16.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice7 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho16.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice7 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho16.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice7 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho16.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice7 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }

            choice8= @"";

            if ([cuartot.lbinsatisfecho17.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice8 = @"Insatisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbpocosatisfecho17.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice8 = @"Poco Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbsatisfecho17.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice8 = @"Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([cuartot.lbmuysatisfecho17.text isEqualToString: @"X"])
            {
                choice8 = @"Muy Satisfecho";
            }

            if ([choice2 isEqualToString:@""] || [choice3 isEqualToString:@""] || [choice4 isEqualToString:@""]  || [choice5 isEqualToString:@""]  || [choice6 isEqualToString:@""]  || [choice7 isEqualToString:@""]  || [choice8 isEqualToString:@""] )
              {
                UIAlertView *alert5 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Faltan campos por llenar" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar"otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert5 show];
                 break;
            }

            else
            {
                quinto *quin = [[quinto alloc]initWithNibName:@"quinto" bundle:nil];
                self.quintot = quin;
                [cuartot.view removeFromSuperview];
                cuartot = nil;
                [self.view insertSubview:quintot.view atIndex:0];
            }
        }
            break;

        case 3:
     {

           primero *ter = [[primero alloc]initWithNibName:@"primero" bundle:nil];
          self.primerot = ter;
           NSInteger row = [quintot.quintoPecker selectedRowInComponent:0];
           choice9 = [quintot.quintoArray objectAtIndex:row];
           [quintot.view removeFromSuperview];
           quintot = nil;

        [self.view insertSubview:primerot.view atIndex:0];
        }
          break;

        case 4:
        {
            septimo *cua = [[septimo alloc]initWithNibName:@"septimo" bundle:nil];
            self.septimot = cua;
        NSInteger row = [primerot.singlePecker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        choice10 = [primerot.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];

            [primerot.view removeFromSuperview];
            primerot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:septimot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 5:
        {
            segundo *quin = [[segundo alloc]initWithNibName:@"segundo" bundle:nil];
            self.segundot = quin;
            NSInteger row = [septimot.septimoPecker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            choice11 = [septimot.septimoArray objectAtIndex:row];

            [septimot.view removeFromSuperview];

            septimot = nil;

            [self.view insertSubview:segundot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;

        case 7:
        {
            septimo *quin = [[septimo alloc]initWithNibName:@"septimo" bundle:nil];
            self.septimot = quin;
            NSInteger row = [quintot.quintoPecker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            choice11 = [quintot.quintoArray objectAtIndex:row];

            [quintot.view removeFromSuperview];

            quintot = nil;

            [self.view insertSubview:septimot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 8:
        {
             decimo *quin = [[decimo alloc]initWithNibName:@"decimo" bundle:nil];
            self.decimot = quin;
            NSInteger row = [segundot.segundoPecker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            choice12 = [segundot.segundoArray objectAtIndex:row];

            [segundot.view removeFromSuperview];

            segundot = nil;

            [self.view insertSubview:decimot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;

        case 10:
        {
              octavo *quin = [[octavo alloc]initWithNibName:@"octavo" bundle:nil];
            self.octavot = quin;

            choice13 = decimot.comentario.text;

       [decimot.view removeFromSuperview];

            decimot = nil;

           [self.view insertSubview:octavot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;


        case 11:
        {
            if ([octavot.email.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
                UIAlertView *alert4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Inserte correo electrónico" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert4 show];

            }
            else {

            cero *quin = [[cero alloc]initWithNibName:@"cero" bundle:nil];
            self.cerot = quin;

            choice14 = octavot.nombre.text;
              choice15 = octavot.email.text;
            choice16 = octavot.facebook.text;
            choice17 = octavot.twitter.text;
        NSInteger row = [octavot.octavoPeckermes selectedRowInComponent:0];

             choice18 = [octavot.octavoArraymes objectAtIndex:row];

        NSInteger row1 = [octavot.octavoPeckermes selectedRowInComponent:1];
            choice19 = [octavot.octavoArraydia objectAtIndex:row1];

            NSMutableArray *encuestas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [encuestas addObject:choice];
            [encuestas addObject:choice2];
            [encuestas addObject:choice3];
            [encuestas addObject:choice4];
            [encuestas addObject:choice5];
            [encuestas addObject:choice6];
            [encuestas addObject:choice7];
            [encuestas addObject:choice8];
            [encuestas addObject:choice9];
            [encuestas addObject:choice10];
            [encuestas addObject:choice11];
            [encuestas addObject:choice12];
            [encuestas addObject:choice13];
            [encuestas addObject:choice14];
            [encuestas addObject:choice15];
            [encuestas addObject:choice16];
            [encuestas addObject:choice17];
            [encuestas addObject:choice18];
            [encuestas addObject:choice19];
           [encuestas  writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

            UIAlertView *alert5 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Muchas Gracias" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert5 show];

           //////sube los datos

            NSFileManager *filemgr;
            filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            NSString *docsDir;
            NSArray *dirPaths;

            dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
            dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"]];

            NSString *urlString = @"http://promocionesveracruzanas.dnsalias.com:8280/NATURAXALV2/subiripad.php";
            NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init] initWithURL:url];

            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
            NSString *filename = @"data.txt";
            NSData *dataChida =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath];
            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataChida]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [request setHTTPBody:body];

            UIAlertView *alert4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NATURA XALAPA" message:@"Enviado con Exito" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert4 show];
         [octavot.view removeFromSuperview];

            octavot = nil;

            [self.view insertSubview:cerot.view atIndex:0];
        }
        }
            break;
    }
 }

- (IBAction) anterior: (id)sender{

    int i;
    if(self.cerot !=nil){  i = 1;}
    if(self.cuartot !=nil){  i = 2;}
    if(self.quintot !=nil){  i = 3;}
    if(self.primerot !=nil){  i = 4;}
    if(self.septimot !=nil){  i = 5;}
    if(self.segundot !=nil){  i = 6;}
    if(self.decimot !=nil){  i = 7;}
    if(self.octavot !=nil){  i = 8;}
    if(self.enviart !=nil){ i =9;}

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            [cerot.view insertSubview:cerot.view atIndex:0];
            cerot = nil;
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            cero *blue =[[cero alloc] initWithNibName:@"cero" bundle:nil];
            self.cerot = blue;
            [cuartot.view removeFromSuperview];
            cuartot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:cerot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            cuarto *blue =[[cuarto alloc] initWithNibName:@"cuarto" bundle:nil];
            self.cuartot = blue;
            [quintot.view removeFromSuperview];
            quintot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:cuartot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 4:
        {
            quinto *blue =[[quinto alloc] initWithNibName:@"quinto" bundle:nil];
            self.quintot = blue;
            [primerot.view removeFromSuperview];
            primerot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:quintot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 5:
        {
            primero *blue =[[primero alloc] initWithNibName:@"primero" bundle:nil];
            self.primerot = blue;
            [septimot.view removeFromSuperview];
            septimot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:primerot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 6:
        {
            septimo *blue =[[septimo alloc] initWithNibName:@"septimo" bundle:nil];
            self.septimot = blue;
            [segundot.view removeFromSuperview];
            segundot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:septimot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 7:
        {
            segundo *blue =[[segundo alloc] initWithNibName:@"segundo" bundle:nil];
            self.segundot = blue;
            [decimot.view removeFromSuperview];
            decimot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:segundot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 8:
        {
            decimo *blue =[[decimo alloc] initWithNibName:@"decimo" bundle:nil];
            self.decimot = blue;
            [octavot.view removeFromSuperview];
            octavot = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:decimot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
        case 9:
        {
            cero *blue =[[cero alloc] initWithNibName:@"cero" bundle:nil];
            self.cerot = blue;
            [enviart.view removeFromSuperview];
            enviart = nil;
            [self.view insertSubview:cerot.view atIndex:0];
        }
            break;
    }   

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    cero *uno = [[cero alloc]initWithNibName:@"cero" bundle:nil];
    self.cerot =uno;
    [self.view insertSubview:uno.view atIndex:0];   
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Vista y conexiones
[image: img1]

Outlets enlazados
[image: img2]

Comment: Ok, ese es el error ... pero para que podamos ayudarte necesitamos ver el código que arroja ese error. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código, describe qué estás tratando de resolver y cuál es el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba en el Inspector del storyboard (zona de la derecha) que no tienes ninguna alerta en los outlets relacionados con esa vista llamada "SwitchClass". Es posible que se haya perdido el enlace a alguno de ellos por cambiar el nombre o algo asi, por lo que te aparecerá un triangulo amarillo junto al nombre del elemento.

En ese caso elimina el outlet y vuélvelo a enlazar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso que lo primero que hice verifique todos los outlets y ninguno marca advertencia o error, de hecho los elimine y volví a enlazar. pero me sigue dando esa excepción.